# Is there any builtin mechanism to stop sql injections in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb, sql-injection

Actually this question is a assignment given to me and I was not able to find any answer by googling. Is there any builtin mechanism in  mariadb to stop sql injections?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-23-database-firewall-filter/

Answer (score 2):

A SQL injection is a execution of a valid syntax that is contrary to the application implementers' intention.

Given the communication of the SQL conforming to the application implementer's intention is solely their responsibility, it its very hard a for a builtin mechanism to realize both the intention and the SQL.

The application implementer needs to use their language constructs of prepared statements to sufficiently separate the data of the application user and the code of the SQL such that user data isn't interpreted as SQL code, contrary to the application implementer's intent.

So prepared statements are the inbuilt communication protocol exposed though application interfaces that should be used in a way that separates user data, and implementer's SQL code that implements their intent.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-23-database-firewall-filter/

Comment: Is it relevant?